# DDD: how to organize builders that bootstrap domain objects? Same Bounded Context?

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I'm restructuring my current project to be better in-line with DDD best practices.

As part of this setup an admin-task allows certain domain-objects / aggregates to be (re)-bootstrapped based on a config file/algo combo. I have a good use-case for this that does require it to be part of a live system as opposed only to testing (text fixtures) for example.

I'm struggling how to best model refactor this in a DDD context:

Basically: would the builders/bootstrappers be infrastructure services belonging to the same Bounded Context as the Domain Objects? Would this feel natural? The flow I see is that an admin gets access to these functions using a special Admin Application Service which in turn calls the builders to do their work.

On the other hand, this admin functionality feels like a separate part of the system so perhaps I shouldn't pollute the domain objects (or their factories) with methods to support the bootstrapping. IOW: this could mean a seperate Bounded Context, with a completely different (logic-less) domain model purely used for persisting to a DB. That however doesn't feel very DRY to me, as I might end up defining models twice (once in each BC)

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by (re)-bootstrapped? Does that have any significance to the domain or is it a technical process?

Comment: What I mean is, say I have a config-file that contains serialized domain objects. I want to be able to change that file and have a builder/bootstrapper load that file in a running system (hot-deploy) so that the domain reflects the changed config-file again.

Comment: What is the business case driving this requirement ?, I do not think its very obvious to have the structure of Domain Objects to change while the application is running, each change in the structure will correspond to changes in the business logic and so will have a ripple effect and should need some testing is'nt it ?